# How many ways of importing data into mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a page in my website which is used for insertion of properties by users which has 54 boxes.

I don't want these information should go directly to my database cause it make it heavy if there will be 200 record per day.

The way i want is to collect the data from users and confirm it, after confirmation i should be able to imported.

May i know how many ways are there for importing data into mysql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$file = '/pathtocsviportdatabase/csv/importtabledata.csv';

$import = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file."' INTO TABLE `imports` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
  (AllCOLUMN SEparated by ',');";
mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

## How many ways of importing data into mysql:

*It should be as simple as...*

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/mydata.txt' INTO TABLE PerformanceReport;
```

*By default `LOAD DATA INFILE` uses tab delimited, one row per line, so should take it in just fine*

***IMPORT***

1. 1.Make sure the database you need has already been created. If it has not, please first create the database:

`How do I create a database?`

**CAUTION:**

`If you import a backup file to a database that already has content, it will replace the existing content.`

1. Use FTP to upload your SQL file to your server. You can upload it to
   your default FTP directory. Or, see Step 1 in the "Export"
   instructions above for another suggestion. Alternately, you can use
   scp to upload your file via SSH.
2. Log into your server via SSH.
3. Use the command cd to navigate into the directory where you uploaded
   your backup file in Step 1. If you uploaded the backup to your data
   directory, go here (replace 00000 with your site number):

   `cd /home/00000/data/`

**Import the database by executing the following command:**

```
`mysql -h internal-db.s00000.gridserver.com -u username -p dbname < dbname.sql`
```

**OR:**

```
`mysql -h internal-db.s00000.gridserver.com -u username -p dbname -e 'source dbname.sql'`
```

1. Once you execute this command, you will be prompted for your
   database password. Type it in and hit enter. Your database will now
   import. It may take a few minutes if you have a large database. When
   the import is done, you will be returned to the command prompt.

**NOTE:**

1. Variables are the same as in Step 3 from the Export section above.
   Please check Step 3 in the "Export" section to make sure you are
   correctly replacing the example code with your own information.

   `dbname.sql is the actual name of your SQL file.`

If you have a gzipped backup of your database, you can use this line instead:

```
`gunzip < dbname.gz | mysql -h internal-db.s00000.gridserver.com -u username -p dbname`
```

1. You can enter in your own username, database name, and backup file
   name, as before. dbname.gz is the name of your gzipped backup file.
   Use "unzip" instead of "gunzip" for zipped files.
2. Remove the SQL file from your web-accessible directory, if you
   uploaded it to a public folder. Otherwise, anyone can download it
   from the web.

If you get an error that looks like this:

```
Got Error: 1045: Access denied for user 'db00000@internal-db.s00000.gridserver.com' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

1. You have entered an incorrect password. Please retype it carefully,
   or reset your password via the AccountCenter Control Panel. See
   Database users on the Grid for instructions.

If you get an SQL error during the import, you can force it to finish by adding "-f" to the command, which stands for "force." For example:

```
`mysql -f -h internal-db.s00000.gridserver.com -u username -p dbname -e 'source dbname.sql'`
```

1. This can help you finish an import if you have a few corrupt tables,
   but need to get the database as a whole imported before you do
   anything else.

***http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html***

***https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/loading-tables.html***

***https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/import/***

***http://www.itworld.com/it-management/359857/3-ways-import-and-export-mysql-database***