# MYSQL Import Data

Tags: mysql

I've a file named `rates.txt` which has the following rows:

```
0.5,28.55,51.3
1,43.74,68.38
1.5,61.62,85.5
2,79.56,102.56
```

I've a MSQL table named `rates` with columns `A,B,C`.

How would I be able to import all the rows in the text file into the mysql table.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL statement [load data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html).

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'rates.txt' INTO TABLE rates 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''
```

Comment: Question, what if I have a primary defined in the table as ID which is auto increment which I dont want to import any data into. Is there any way the LOAD DATA can skip 1 field and only take into acocunt the rest of the fields?

Comment: Adding column names at the end of statement works, but does not increment id sequentially after importing the second time. ID is like 1,2,3,4, 8,9,10,11, ... Statement: LOAD DATA INFILE 'rates.txt' INTO TABLE rates 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY '' (a, b, c)

Answer (score 0):

*It should be as simple as...*

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/mydata.txt' INTO TABLE PerformanceReport;
```

*By default `LOAD DATA INFILE` uses tab delimited, one row per line, so should take it in just fine*

***sample code:***

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'abc.txt' INTO TABLE abc
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5...)
```

***refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22801922/3242978***

Comment: Question, what if I have a primary defined in the table as ID which is auto increment which I don't want to import any data into. Is there any way the LOAD DATA can skip 1 field and only take into account the rest of the fields?